# Unity via configuration - property dependency injection in generic base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, configuration, dependency-injection, unity-container

I got lost searching for solution to this problem:

I have interface:

```
public interface ITestService
{
    ...
}
```

Then, I have base class with that implements that interface and has other service as property:

```
public class BaseTestServiceImpl<T> : ITestService, IDisposable where T : class
{
    protected T GenericProperty;

    public IOtherService OtherService;

    public void ExampleMethodFromBase()
    {
        OtherService.DoSomething();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Finally, I have several classes that inherit that base class. Example for one of them:

```
public class SpecificTestServiceImpl : BaseTestServiceImpl<SomeType>
{
    public void ExampleMethodFromSpecific()
    {
        OtherService.DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

Controller that calls methods from **SpecificTestServiceImpl** looks like this:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [Dependency("TestService")]
    public BaseTestServiceImpl<SomeType> TestService { get; set; }

    public JsonResult TestAction()
    {
        TestService.ExampleMethodFromSpecific();
    }
}
```

Unity configuration looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

    <configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
    </configSections>

    <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <container>
        <alias alias="transient" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.TransientLifetimeManager, Microsoft.Practices.Unity" />
        <alias alias="MyType" type="SomeType" />
        <register name="otherService" type="IOtherService" mapTo="OtherServiceImpl">
            <lifetime type="singleton" />
        </register>
        <register type="ITestService" mapTo="BaseTestServiceImpl`1[]">
            <lifetime type="transient" />
            <property name="OtherService" dependencyName="otherService" />
        </register>
        <register name="TestService" type="BaseTestServiceImpl`1[MyType]" mapTo="SpecificTestServiceImpl">
            <lifetime type="singleton" />
        </register>
    </container>
    </unity>
</configuration>
```

Everything is resolved just fine, until the moment **TestAction** from **TestController** is called. Then I get NullPointerException in this line:

```
OtherService.DoSomethingElse();
```

in **ExampleMethodFromSpecific** method from **SpecificTestServiceImpl**.

It looks like Unity skips parent property injection in child classes.

Can this be done? I've tried setting other lifetime managers to **BaseTestServiceImpl** registration, but it failed the same way.

Please, help. I'm lost. :(

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to have the complete configuration in XML? You should only configure the part of the DI configuration in XML that actually can change during deployment. For the rest, use code based configuration, since XML based configuration is less expressive, more brittle, error prone, and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Now it's been a while since I used unity, and I do prefer to have the config fully in code, but:
The requested type in the controller is  `[Dependency("TestService")]` which is configured as a `SpecificTestServiceImpl` which in turn has not been configured. I would have thought that Unity would have told you that `SpecificTestServiceImpl` is not configured, but perhaps it does use the mapped type, which is concrete

I just have to add that this mix of public members, interfaces, injected concrete types is rather poorly encapsulated logic and removes quite a lot of the value that a proper design would. The test controller should preferably request an interface ISomeTypeTestService (or similar), which in turn could be mapped to the BaseTestServiceImpl, or it could be a named ITestService which could be requested as it is now

Comment: First I want to thank you for your answer. As for your proposal - I've simplified the code so that I could explain my problem more easily, so some obvious mistakes may lay there even though I tried to make valid example. I'm quite sure that problem lies in parent->child registration resolving, since Unity configuration is resolved without any error.

Comment: Ok, but do check that you are requesting a type where the property has been configured as a dependency, because as the example is now, you are requesting a type that has a property, but nothing has configured it as a dependency to be resolved. Try to add the dependency attribute to the otherservice in the base class: `[Dependency]public IOtherService OtherService;`

Comment: This line in Unity config does that injection: `<property name="OtherService" dependencyName="otherService" />`

Comment: Yeah, but that is not the dependency the controller is requesting

Comment: Controller is requesting `TestService` dependency, and that one works just fine since it crashes inside the `ExampleMethodFromSpecific()` method, where `OtherService` is **null** hence not resolved by Unity.

Comment: You are resolving testservice. The property is configured on itestservice. Your configuration is wrong. So yes, unity does not resolve the itestservice because you haven't told it to.

Comment: Nope. Property is configured on `BaseTestServiceImpl`, and `ITestService` is just an interface it's implementing. It's like doing this from application block: `container.RegisterType<ITestService, BaseTestServiceImpl'1>();` only with additional definition of configuration-based property dependency injection.

Comment: You know you could try adding the dependency attribute like i said before. I'm not being much help obviously so I hope you find the solution anyway.